# Cakephp and moodle on the same server cpanel

Tags: php, cakephp, cpanel, moodle

i have my site published on a server. I'm using CakePHP to this site. Now i want to integrate a Moodle (is something like Wordpress or Joomla) but, when i'm trying to access to the moodle folder (on the server) there is a problem.... because CakePHP try to match the folder moodle like it was a CakePHP controller... but it isn't ... what can i do to have both aplications running on the same server?. I think i have to do something on the cpanel but i don't know what exactly.

PD. Excuse my bad english xD

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code of .htaccess file in root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks..!